# How to align text next to a "div" in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, text-align

I have put an image map to my website with multiple colours, so I wanted to make a "div" block and next to it an explanation of what that colour represents on the map. But, when I try to do it, the text just goes under the "div", like so:

```css
#dark_green {height: 40px;
width: 80px;
background-color: #009933; }

#light_green {height: 40px;
width: 80px;
background-color: #00ff00;
 }

#dark_red {height: 40px;
width: 80px;
background-color: #ff0000;
 }

#light_orange {height: 40px;
width: 80px;
background-color: #ff8c1a;
 }
```

```html
<div id="dark_green"></div> - Dark Green
<br>
<div id="light_green"></div> - Light Green
<br>
<div id="dark_red"></div> - Dark Red
<br>
<div id="light_orange"></div> - Light Orange
```

How can I make the text align next to each of the "divs"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the markup you gave us here, just make all the boxes displaying as an `inline-block`.

**Notice**: Just add the things, which make an element unique, to an `id`. All the rest, which is the same for multiple elements, should be in a `class`. Why? If you want to make the box - let's say - 20px wider, you will have to edit *every box-id* at the moment, with my improvement in your code, you just have to *edit the class once and you're all done*.

**Edit**: Wrap your explanations into an element, a `<span>` would be just fine here. Then you are able to apply styles to them (position, color, etc.).

```css
.box {
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.explanation {
    margin-left: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#dark_green {
    background-color: #009933;
}

#light_green {
    background-color: #00ff00;
}

#dark_red {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

#light_orange {
    background-color: #ff8c1a;
}
```

```html
<div id="dark_green" class="box"></div><span class="explanation">- Dark Green</span>
<br>
<div id="light_green" class="box"></div><span class="explanation">- Light Green</span>
<br>
<div id="dark_red" class="box"></div><span class="explanation">- Dark Red</span>
<br>
<div id="light_orange" class="box"></div><span class="explanation">- Light Orange</span>
```

Comment: The text should probably be wrapped in an element, maybe a `span`. This makes it possible to position the text with `vertical-align`.

Comment: You are right, didn't want to confuse him with too much input at one time. I will edit the answer in a second.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

```css
#color_box_wrapper{
  display: table;
}

#color_box, #color_text{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}

#color_text{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.dark_green {
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: #009933; 
}

.light_green {
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: #00ff00;
}

.dark_red {
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.light_orange {
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: #ff8c1a;
}
```

```html
<div id="color_box_wrapper"><div id="color_box" class="dark_green"></div><p id="color_text"> - Dark Green</p></div>
<br>
<div id="color_box_wrapper"><div id="color_box" class="light_green"></div><p id="color_text"> - Light Green</p></div>
<br>
<div id="color_box_wrapper"><div id="color_box" class="dark_red"></div><p id="color_text"> - Dark Red</p></div>
<br>
<div id="color_box_wrapper"><div id="color_box" class="light_orange"></div><p id="color_text"> - Light Orange</p></div>
```

https://codepen.io/TriggeredOnCode/pen/PGogEz